# ASP.NET Core 2.2 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for http

Tags: asp.net-core

I am struggling to get an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application to listen for http requests.

When I start the application `dotnet run --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000`
the command returns `Now listening on: https://[::]:5001`

And when trying to access the url: `http://localhost:5000`

I get an error message in the browser stating `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

**Https connections do work on port 5001, but Http on port 5000 fail.**

My `launcSettings.json` looks like this:

```
"commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000;https://localhost:5001",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
```

Please help by suggesting how to enable http.

I have disabled the HttpsRedirection in the `Starup.cs`, but this also has no effect:

```
        app.UseStatusCodePages();            
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this scenario, ensure that the `Program` class configures the WebHost correctly.

In the example below, two URL strings `.UseUrls("https://*:5001;http://*:5000")`
are provided to configure the `WebHost`, ensuring the service accepts both https and http on the tcp ports 5001 and 5000.

e.g.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("https://*:5001;http://*:5000")  
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```